# Do not submit form on onchange event

Tags: javascript, forms

```
            <form class="form1">
              <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
                 <option value="">Select a country...</option>
                 <option value="United States">United States</option>
                 <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                 <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan etc...</option>
              </select>
            <input type="text" />
            <button type="submit" />
            </form>

            <form class="form2">
              <select>
                 <option value="">Select a country...</option>
                 <option value="United States">United States</option>
                 <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                 <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan etc...</option>
              </select>
            <input type="text" />
            <button type="submit" />
            </form>
```

this.form.submit() submits form on option change. What would be the opposite to this? 
Submitting the form on change is not required. It is only required when the submit button is clicked.

Form 2 submits on change. How to get rid of it.

Comment: Why is onchanging invoking submit if "Submitting the form on change is not required"?

Comment: The issue seems to be in the button tag as per my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You're issue is in the button tag. It cannot be called as `<button />`. You basically have the second form acting as a button. The following code should work and uses `onSubmit()` for the second form:

```
<form class="form1">
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
             <option value="">Select a country...</option>
             <option value="United States">United States</option>
             <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
             <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan etc...</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Click me</button>
 </form>
 <form class="form2" onSubmit="doSomething()">
     <select>
             <option value="">Select a country...</option>
             <option value="United States">United States</option>
             <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
             <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan etc...</option>
     </select>
     <input type="text" />
     <button type="submit">Click me</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: I don't see how I was wrong as he said: `Submitting the form on change is not required. It is only required when the submit button is clicked.`

Comment: None of what you've quoted is a question.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted, he is right about the button tag.

Comment: My original answer was just telling them to use onSubmit() in the form tag. Which I guess confused people...

Comment: Which had nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: Considering he asked how to submit when the submit button was clicked instead, I think you'll find it did.

Comment: He already had a button with `type="submit"`. He is asking how to *remove* the submit that is happening onchange.

Comment: An the reason it is happening onchange is because the second form (the one he wants to remove the onchange event from occurring) is wrapped entirely inside the incorrectly written button tag as interpreted by browsers. Button tags cannot be self-closing.

Comment: An incorrect button tag with a submit attribute won't submit a form to anything... Look dude there's 0 point arguing this. Either way the issue is solved now.

Comment: I was arguing that the original answer posted did not solve anything. Still, there is no reason to tell them to use onsubmit, as they're not trying to execute any function on submit.

Comment: But there is seeing as they said: `Submitting the form on change is not required. It is only required when the submit button is clicked.` So obviously they want something to happen once the submit button is clicked.

Comment: They want the form to submit when the button is clicked. You don't need `onsubmit` for that.

Comment: The HTML as written in the question features 2 button tags that are improperly written. When interpreted by a browser, the first one ends up wrapping the entire second form as its inner content, hence the main point of the answer. The second button also is broken and wouldn't trigger a form to submit on click. However this answer fixes both issues by writing out proper button tags. Perhaps the onSubmit portion of the form tag can be considered unnecessary but the answer as a whole is correct.

Comment: I'll agree with Rich here as it puts the whole thing to bed. Thanks all for your input.

Comment: The submit button tags are written incorrectly, that is right. But only in here. Not in the actual code. On this forum it is just a typo.  And it has no effect on how the browser generates the button tags.
In other words: editing <button /> to <button></button> doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<form>
 <!-- Note that the onchange has been removed //-->
 <select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">Select a country...</option>
     <option value="United States">United States</option>
     <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
     <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan etc...</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit/>
</form>
```

You just remove `onchange="this.form.submit()"` which stops the form getting submitted when the select value changes.